# How many matrix colorings are possible?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, permutations

We have a small square matrix having size up to $8$. And we have a large number of colors up to $10^6$. In how many ways we can color the matrix so that all the same color cells are not adjacent? Cells are adjacent if there is any common edge between them.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE, Seema.  It would help us to provide useful Answers if you spell out the context of your Question in greater detail, and share what approaches or difficulties you already know about in this connection.

Answer (score 0):

let the cells be numbered like 1, 2,3 ... starting from top left corner we have $10^6$ ways for $1^{st}$ cell, $10^6-1$ for second to eight cell. considering $9^{th}$ as the one below $1^{st}$ cell the no of possible ways is again $10^6-1$, and for $10^{th}$ to $16^{th}$ cell the No of ways is $10^6-2$ and so on therefore the Total No of turns out to be $$10^6(10^6-1)^{7\times8}(10^6-2)^{7\times7}$$
if you assume $10^6-1 \approx 10^6-2 \approx  10^6 $ then the formula can be simplified to $10^{6*64}$ this i think is ok if colors can be re used